# HTML validation error: "Non-space character in page trailer"

Tags: html, validation

I run a W3C validation on [this site](http://nibbler.silktide.com/en_US/reports/www.amberaviationacademy.com.au).

One of the error is saying [this page](https://www.amberaviationacademy.com.au/courses) has "non-space character in page trailer" at source code.

[image: Validation error]

I am not sure where to find the issue.

Comment: To help emphasize the point made elsewhere, you did not use any W3C validator at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintainer of the [W3C HTML Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) (validator) here. That *“Non-space character in page trailer”* error is caused by [the “Nibbler” tool](http://nibbler.silktide.com/en_US) you’re using. Use https://validator.w3.org/nu/ directly instead.

https://www.amberaviationacademy.com.au/courses is one of the documents that [Nibbler reports](http://nibbler.silktide.com/en_US/reports/www.amberaviationacademy.com.au#Test_Page_CodeQuality) that *“Non-space character in page trailer”* error for.

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https://www.amberaviationacademy.com.au/courses in contrast shows what the HTML checker reports when you use it directly.

No *“Non-space character in page trailer”* error is reported when you use the HTML checker directly.

So, Nibbler’s “W3C Compliance” checking is broken and shouldn’t be trusted, but instead avoided.

Save yourself time and confusion and always just use https://validator.w3.org/nu/ directly instead.

Comment: Well, we're using vnu jar npm package and we still get exactly that issue, even though like you suggested the original validator is used. We can't find out the reason.